# I am getting an error when I try "npm install gh-pages --save-dev". This is for hosting website on GitHub

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages, host

```
(base) XXXXXXX@XXXXs-MacBook-Pro portfolio copy % npm install gh-pages --save-dev

> npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
> npm ERR! syscall rename
> npm ERR! path /Users/xxxxxxxxx/Desktop/portfolio copy/node_modules/jest-changed-files/node_modules/which
> npm ERR! dest /Users/xxxxxxxxx/Desktop/portfolio copy/node_modules/jest-changed-files/node_modules/.which-D8F24LMI
> npm ERR! errno -66
> npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/portfolio copy/node_modules/jest-changed-files/node_modules/which' -> '/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/portfolio copy/node_modules/jest-changed-files/node_modules/.which-D8F24LMI'

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /Users/XXXXXXXX/.npm/_logs/2021-07-01T16_12_29_442Z-debug.log
```